# Improving initial rendering of Azure B2C custom policy frontend UI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using Azure B2C custom policy for authentication, and I have a frontend HTML/CSS issue. When a customer opens the xxxx.b2clogin.com URL, the initial rendering is unstyled and looks ugly. The CSS and styles slowly load afterward, resulting in a visually pleasing UI.

I would like to improve the user experience by avoiding the initial ugly rendering and ensuring that the page looks good from the beginning. What can I do at the HTML and JavaScript level to address this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can [add data-preload="true"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content). This forces the page to be rendered before it is displayed to the user. It is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content).

```
<link href="https://path-to-your-file/sample.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-preload="true"/>
```